# HAproxy ACLs to Allow ssh git operations to only selected git repositories / project urls ( block all other repos)

Tags: ssh, haproxy, bitbucket

I have Bitbucket Server serving SSH git traffic on port 7999 and it has an HAProxy for SSH port forwarding ( HAProxy is only for a set of users from a secure n/w).

The requirement is to Allow only selected projects/repos to be cloned using SSH protocol which has to pass through HAproxy on port  7999. Port forwarding is  working however ACL is not yet working.

The git SSH clone URL looks as:

```
git clone ssh://git@mydomain.name.com:7999/project1/repo1.git
```

Question1)Is this can be achieved using HAproxy ACLs for SSH URIs?
Question2) I am a beginner on HAproxy ACL, how to write a HAproxy rule so that block all repos by default and allow only selected repos?

I tried
`deny if {path -i -m end reponame.git}` however not succeeded.

seeking example/guidance on how best we can achieve it using HAproxy.

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy doesn't terminate a `ssh` connection so it is unable to look into paths. `path` can be matched only with HTTP requests (haproxy `mode http`).